# Adding more movement to randomization, adding a grid with matrices: Tkinter, Python

Tags: python, tkinter, random

I am trying to make a ball move randomly in all direction (up, down, right, left, diagonally) as well as implement a grid using matrices. Each box in the grid will hold a value of 20 and when the ball moves over a box, the value of the box goes down by one.

***My main issue is giving the ball more movement, as in not just diagonally.***

 Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
import time

class Ball: 
    def __init__(self,canvas,color):
        width = 1280
        height = 720        
        self.alive = True
        self.canvas = canvas 
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(30, 30, 50, 50, fill=color) 
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 640, 360)
        self.vx = randint(0,2)
        self.vy = randint(0,2)
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width() 
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height() 

    def move(self): 
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.vx, self.vy) 
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id) 
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.vx = 1
        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.vx = -1
        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.vy = 1
        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height: 
            self.vy = -1

    def kill(self):
        self.alive = False

def main():
    tk = Tk()
    tk.title("Bee Ball")
    tk.resizable(False, False)
    tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
    canvas = Canvas(tk, bg="white", width=1280, height=720, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
    canvas.pack()
    tk.update()

    tk.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: ball1.kill())

    ball1 = Ball(canvas, "black")
    while ball1.alive:
        tk.update()
        ball1.move()
        time.sleep(0.005)
    tk.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If anyone can help with than and possibly with the grid/give me some resource to look into how to make a grid with tkinter or help with matrices, that would be cool.

Comment: _"My main issue is giving the ball more movement."_ is rather vague. What do you mean by "more movement"?

Comment: I am trying to make a ball move randomly in all direction (up, down, right, left, diagonally). Right now, the ball just moves diagonally from the middle of the screen to the right bottom corner. I don't know how to go about this.

Comment: The solution is just basic math. Have you tried changing the values of `self.vx` and `self.vy`?

Comment: Yes. I have, but the ball only moves in diagonals. The goal is when it moves it should move around the entire screen and not just in one path.

Comment: If you change the x but not the y it moves horizontally.

Comment: I know, but is there a way to make it move in more than one direction and not just diagonally or horizontally?

Comment: Change the x coordinate it moves horizontally, change the y it moves vertically. Change both of them and it moves in some other direction. Add to the x coordinate it moves right. Subtract from the x coordinate it moves left. And so on. It's just that simple.